# How to use C# 9 records with EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, c#-9.0

I am using ASP.NET Core 5 Web API and I am trying to use the new [C# records](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/c-9-0-on-the-record/) as my model classes. But I am getting an EF Core error about tracking problems whenever I update my modified model using the `with` expression:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Product' cannot be
tracked because another instance with the key value '{ID: 2}' is already being
tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance
with a given key value is attached.
```

I believe this is due to how "mutating" records creates a new object instance and EF Core's tracking system doesn't like that, but I'm not sure the best way to fix it. Does anyone have any recommendations? Or should I go back to using regular classes instead of records?

Here's a snippet to reproduce the problem:

```cs
// Models/Product.cs
public record Product(int ID, string Name);


// Controllers/ProductController.cs
[HttpGet("test/{id}")]
public async Task<Product> ExampleControllerAction(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    string newName = "test new name!!";

    Product product = await db.Products.FindAsync(new object[] { id }, cancellationToken);
    product = product with { Name = newName }; // Modify the model.

    db.Update(product); // InvalidOperationException happens here.
    await db.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

    return product;
}
```

Comment: What's your purpose of using record type over class? Any benefits? I don't see any benefits here. You just look like wanting to try something new but not even sure when that new thing should be used. Record types should be used in case you want the data to be immutable and adjusted over-time into ***new*** instances. Although you can define it to support mutable data, but it's then much like classes and has no benefits over classes.

Comment: Immutability by default and more succinct code. But it looks like EF Core tracking isn't really compatible with immutable classes, so I guess I'll have to switch back to regular classes.

Comment: Correct, the EF Core change tracker does not work well with records

Comment: @KingKing Thanks for the comment about `with`, I totally missed that logic.

Comment: I believe the crux of the problem is that *with* creates a copy of the record with the changes in place. When you assign the product the new record, it loses the object reference that EF Core depends on for change tracking.

Answer (score 55):

From [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/records)

> Entity Framework Core depends on reference equality to ensure that it
> uses only one instance of an entity type for what is conceptually one
> entity. For this reason, record types aren't appropriate for use as
> entity types in Entity Framework Core.

This could confuse some people. Pay close attention to the documentation. `record`s might not be suited for entities, but they are just fine for owned types for example, like value objects (in DDD-terms), because such values don't have a conceptual unique identity.

For example, if an Address entity, modeled as a class, owns a City value object, modeled as a record, EF would usually map City as **columns** inside Address like this: `City_Name`, `City_Code`, etc. (ie. record name joined with an underscore and the property name).

Notice that City has no Id, because we're not tracking unique cities here, just names and codes and whatever other information you could add to a City.

Whatever you do, don't add Ids to records and try to map them manually, because two records with the same Id don't necessarily mean the same conceptual entity to EF, probably because EF compares object instances by reference (records are ref types) and doesn't use the standard equality comparer which is different for records than for standard objects (needs confirmation).

I myself don't know how EF's works on the inside very well to talk with more certainty, but I trust the docs and you should probably trust them too, unless you want to read the source code.

Answer (score 21):

If you turn off EFs change tracking it should work as written. Try adding `AsNoTracking()` to the original db call.

Comment: Mike, you can post on meta to raise a bug/feature request/worry/etc

Comment: No problem +1 for the case.

Comment: In this case you can use EF Core like micro ORMs... I like this.

Answer (score 10):

Current docs state...

> Reference equality is required for some data models. For example,
> Entity Framework Core depends on reference equality to ensure that it
> uses only one instance of an entity type for what is conceptually one
> entity. For this reason, **records and record structs aren't appropriate
> for use as entity types in Entity Framework Core** [emphasis mine].
>
> -[Records (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#value-equality)

...however, this does not negate [Mike Weiss'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67560727/3246805) `AsNoTracking()` alternative.

Comment: Microsoft's official statement makes no sense... while it's true that `record` types do `override Equals`, EF and .NET has _always_ been able to bypass custom `Equals` overrides with `Object.ReferenceEquals` and go beyond with `ConditionalWeakTable` etc - so I don't know why this is apparently a problem for them... (and use of `==` in Linq expressions doesn't matter either: EF has the `Expression<>` tree object and can bind `==` to `Object.ReferenceEquals` instead of always using `static operator==`)

Comment: @Dai It seems ef used `Object.ReferenceEquals` and therefore you cannot add another instance with the same key. The problem is that we want change the instance that it is tracked before.

Answer (score 3):

I think a great use case for record types+EF Core is the compiler generated "help" you get for equality/comparison stuff.

Consider an EF Core Query like this:

```cs
var result = 
    (from pt in context.ParentTable
    from c in pt.Children
    select new {
        pt.Id,
        pt.Name,
        c.Kinship,
        ChildName = c.Name
    }).Distinct().ToArray();
```

This is a very efficient way in EF Core to retrieve data out of the table where you don't need to update either table involved. You select just the columns you need, EF Core won't track the outputs, and you avoided `select *`'s, which is HUGE.

The `Distinct`, in this case, will be run DB-side, and will be nice and performant. For the demonstration, if you reverse the `Distinct().ToArray()` to `.ToArray().Distinct()` then, you pull all the matching records from the DB, and do the Distinct client-side. Not exactly ideal, but this "just works" because the Anonymous type we're using is acting like a record type under the covers. Anonymous types are great like that. Use em.

Now, consider you had to refactor this thing and you can't use an Anonymous type. Maybe you want to pass the results of this query to some other method and don't want to use dynamic. Your only real option is to define a class to contain all of the data.

```cs
public class ParentChild {
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public string Kinship { get;set; }
    public string ChildName { get;set; }
}

var result = 
    (from pt in context.ParentTable
    from c in pt.Children
    select new ParentChild() {
        Name = pt.Name,
        Kinship = c.Kinship,
        ChildName = c.Name
    }).AsEnumerable().Distinct().ToArray(); //Emphasis on running the distinct operation Client-Side, not db-side
```

On the surface, this looks like it would be just fine. The query is the same, and we've just changed the Anonymous type to a concrete one. But, you're not going to get the distinct list of records you want anymore! This is because we didn't provide an implementation of GetHashCode, override .Equals, nor provided an IEqualityComparer to the Distinct. This code will, in fact, run like the Distinct() isn't even there.

If you change up the intermediate type to be a record type, then client-side `.Distinct()` will do what you expect.

```cs
public record class ParentChild {
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public string Kinship { get;set; }
    public string ChildName { get;set; }
}
//Adding record automatically adds comparison stuff, suitable for sorting and distinction
```

I think what's important to note here based on what the documentation is trying to say, is not to use one of these intermediate optimized query types as an entity (try to attach it to the EF Context or mutate this thing and later call SaveChanges()). It's not saying record types are off limits for other EF adjacent purposes, like DTOs, type mappings, or ViewModels.

---

Just to sort of tack on some additional info here; if you're using some earlier version of C# and record isn't available, the VS IDE has an extract class helper function, which will generate a DIY record type:

```cs
public class ParentChild
{
    public ParentChild(string name, string kinship, string childName)
    {
        Name = name;
        Kinship = kinship;
        ChildName = childName;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public string Kinship { get; }
    public string ChildName { get; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is ParentChild other &&
                Name == other.Name &&
                Kinship == other.Kinship &&
                ChildName == other.ChildName;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        //Smaller classes will use a HashCode.Combine() overload, rather than hash.Add like below
        var hash = new HashCode();
        hash.Add(Name);
        hash.Add(Kinship);
        hash.Add(ChildName);
        return hash.ToHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the other answers, I have attempted to use records with EF Core 7, to hold the results of a projection (`.Select()`), as an alternative to using anonymous types.

The records work fine for the most part, however if you use the records constructor, EF can no longer track the values that you passed into the constructor once they come back out as properties.

For example, if you use records for the last projection before performing the query, it'll work just fine:

```
await blah.Select(o => new SomeRecord(o.Thing, o.Doodlydo))
.ToListAsync()
```

However, if you attempt to navigate further into the property, it won't work:

```
blah.Select(o => new SomeRecord(o.Thing, o.Doodlydo))
.Select(sr => sr.Thing.InnerThing)
```

EF will throw the typical "cannot translate query" exception, because it no longer understands that the record property is a projection of what was passed into the record constructor.

However, if you construct the record by passing in `default` in the constructor, and then set its properties, it *does* work:

```
blah.Select(o => new SomeRecord(default, default) {
    Thing = o.Thing,
    Doodlydo = o.Doodlydo
})
.Select(sr => sr.Thing.InnerThing)
```

Because EF knows what the properties are again, because it saw them being set.